# Output of two different queries as one result in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two different tables and I want to get these two different output in single result. Here I want to display the result of both queries in single report.

Query 1

```
Select name, sum(purchasqty)-sum (soldqty) as pending 
from (select p.name, p.qty as purchasqty, s.qty as soldqty 
      from purchase p 
      left join sold s on p.id = s.id ) 
group by name;
```

Query 2

```
Select name, sum(qty) as damage 
from purchase p 
where con = 'c' 
group by name
```

Comment: How do you want the output to look?

Comment: Have a look for `UNION ALL` maybe.

Comment: To APC 5.....i want to display all columns of query 1 and 2.

Comment: Union all is only display 1 query result..

Comment: To APC 5....I want to display all columns of  both queries.. ..i tried union all but it only shows first query result..

Answer (score 0):

This will do

```
Select name, sum(purchasqty)-sum (soldqty) as pending, '' as damage 
from (select p.name, p.qty as purchasqty, s.qty as soldqty 
      from purchase p 
      left join sold s on p.id = s.id ) 
group by name
union all 
Select name, '' as pending,  sum(qty) as damage 
from purchase p 
where con = 'c' 
group by name
```

Comment: Expression mist have same datatypes as corresponding expression.

Comment: @AmanNagra Edit your question with sample expected output result. so that i can edit the answer.

Comment: ...Expected Result .....i want result in 3 columns...name  pending. Damage

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky because you seem to be aggregating at a level different from what you are joining on.  I would recommend:

```
select p.name, (p.purchasqty - coalesce(ps.soldqty, 0) as pending ,
       p.damage
from (select p.name, sum(qty) as purchase_qty,
             sum(case when con = 'c' then qty else 0 end) as damage
      from purchase p
      group by p.name
     ) p left join
     (select p.name, sum(s.qty) as soldqty 
      from purchase p join
           sold s
           on p.id = s.id
      group by p.name
     ) ps
     on ps.name = p.name;
```